# Making GRUB see software RAID 0 under Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD

Tags: ubuntu, grub, raid, ubuntu-10.10, raid-0

I just installed Windows 7 recently, and I expect that it would alter GRUB and it did.

I've been following some guides around and I am always stuck at GRUB not able to detect the usual RAID content. (Software RAID 0)

I've tried running:

```
sudo grub

> root (hd0,0)
```

GRUB complains it couldn't find my hard disk. So I tried:

```
find (hd0,0)
```

And it complains that it couldn't find anything.

So I tried:

```
find /boot/grub/stage1
```

It said "file not found".

Here's the text from the console:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ grub
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.

       [ Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported.   For
         the   first   word,  TAB  lists  possible  command
         completions.  Anywhere else TAB lists the possible
         completions of a device/filename. ]
grub> root (hd0,0)
root (hd0,0)

Error 21: Selected disk does not exist
grub> find /boot/grub/stage1
find /boot/grub/stage1

Error 15: File not found
```

So what now? How can we make GRUB see RAID 0 under Ubuntu 10.10 LiveCD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/19789/restoring-grub2-on-software-raid-0-using-livecd-after-windows-7-wiped-it/19867#19867

Answer (score 0):

Is it a software raid or an hardware raid?

Take a look at this -> http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic.php?p=2053048

Comment: This is software RAID 0.

Comment: I have tried in the link provided. It is very similar to what I did before. Nope, it doesn't work.